# PHP regex unexpected match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

i have a regex in my php code that should match every number and all "operators" +-*/^r() my regex looks like this

`/(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)|(\+)|(-)|(\*)|(\/)|(\^)|(r)|(\()|(\))))/`

and when tested with the string `preg_match_all($expression,"2+2",$results)` it gives me back

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => '+'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ''
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => '+'
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
           [0] => ''
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => ''
    )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => ''
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => ''
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => ''
        )

    [8] => Array
        (    
            [0] => ''
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => ''
        )

)
```

When (if it works right) i should be getting this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => '2'
            [1] => '+'
            [2] => '2'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => '2'
            [1] => ''
            [2] => '2'
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ''
            [1] => '+'
            [2] = > ''
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
           [0] => ''
           [1] => ''
           [2] => ''
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
           [0] => ''
           [1] => ''
           [2] => ''
        )
    ...

)
```

*Note, it returns similar behaviour for all of the operators, it seems to ignore the numbers entirely*

*Note, I DO need separate capture groups so i have different match indexes for each result*

Comment: What is the goal of this?

Comment: "should match every number and all "operators" +-*/^r()" i am trying to tokenize based on this regex

Comment: Then you don't need to use separated capture groups

Comment: sorry, somewhat new to regex, you mean rather than my current i should use what instead? maybe post an answer rather than a comment

Comment: @casimiretHippolyte sorry, upon looking into it, i do need separate capture groups, because i need a 2D array separated on the indexes of each result, i need to take a different action depending on the token and i'd rather match strings _once_ and be done

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do this:

```
$pattern = '~\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[-+*/^r()]~';
```

Comment: dont the `-^()` all need to be escaped?

Comment: @Nanos: You don't need to escape these characters inside a character class. `~` is the pattern delimiter (as `/` or `#`)